# Map Realm Result to JSON Standard format

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

How would I proceed to map a realm result to a JSON format.
Here are my Realm object classes.

```
class OrderItemList: Object {

dynamic var dateCreated = NSDate()
let orderItems = List<OrderItem>()
}

class OrderItem: Object {

dynamic var name = " "
dynamic var amount = 0
dynamic var internalUnique = Int()
dynamic var isCompleted = false
}
```

I want to map the result of the data saved and send it to an API like so:

```
let orderRequestUserValues  = [  "ClientID": "TEST",
                                     "UserName": "sysadmin",
                                     "Password": "123456",
                                     "ModuleID": "StockProcessing",
                                     "FunctionID": "SetStockOrder",
                                     "TransmissionFlags": 32,
                                     "TransmissionMethod": 5,
                                     "RequestParameters":
                                     [
                                        "OrderType": 1,
                                        "Notes": "John Is Reordering",
                                        "ListofStockItemOrderData":  //Here is where the mapped JSON will be
                                                            ]

        ]
```

Via Alamofire:

```
manager.request(.POST, url, parameters: orderRequestUserValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following function to your `OrderItemList` to convert its `orderItems` List to a JSON string:

```
func orderItemsJSON() throws -> String? {
  let serializableOrderItems = Array(orderItems.map({ item in
    return [
      "name": item.name,
      "amount": item.amount,
      "internalUnique": item.internalUnique,
      "isCompleted": item.isCompleted
    ]
  }))
  let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: serializableOrderItems, options: .prettyPrinted)
  return String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
}
```